# Auto run a file before handling http call made via URL

Tags: php, http

Just want to find out if this is possible.

When I call `http://localhost/TEST/folder_validation/1.pdf` via browser, validate.php should run before to update 'log.txt' and redirect user to different URL.

Current solution below won't work.

Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

Thanks

**FOLDER STRUCTURE:**

```
folder_validation/1.pdf
folder_validation/2.pdf
folder_validation/log.txt
folder_validation/validate.php
folder_validation/.htaccess
folder_validation/..............
```

**Content of validate.php file: (*Won't update log file*)**

```
$file = 'log.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $_GET['filename'] . "\n";
file_put_contents($file, $current);

header('Location: http://stackoverflow.com/');
exit;
```

**Content of .htaccess file: (As suggested answers below)**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /validate.php?filename=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Any examples you know on web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /validate.php?filename=$1 [L]
```

And in validate.php you can get the requested filename in the get parameter filename.

Answer (score 0):

1-> Create a .htaccess file(when saving file write it within double-quotes like ".htaccess").

2->

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.+\.pdf)$ /folder/validate.php?file=$1
```